# Use segmented horizontal line to indicate column groups in a table

Tags: latex

I am looking to break the horizontal lines in a Table to indicate grouping of several columns.

[image: A picture for horizontal lines with breaks]

Is there an elegant solution in Latex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `booktabs` is the suitable option for achieving what you desire, coupled with the command `\multicolumns`.

`booktabs` lets you use the `cmidrule` command: the first argument is, in this case, `lr` which means that you want to trimmer the left and the right part of the line, while the second argument refers to the columns you want to spam with this line. Check [here](https://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf#page=4) for further information.

The command `multirow` allows a text to span multiple columns: the first argument is the number of columns to be spanned, the second is the alignement and the third the text of the cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{XXX} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{XXX} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{XXX}\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-9}
xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx &  xx & xx & xx \\
xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx &  xx & xx & xx \\
xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx &  xx & xx & xx \\
xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx &  xx & xx & xx \\
xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx &  xx & xx & xx \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @YutongXie Glad to help! If you want, mark the answer as accepted for future users which may search for a solution to the same problem.